# Sup inequalties

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to check if these following inequalities are true

$$
\left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} (f_s + g_s) \right| \leq 
\left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} f_s \right| + \left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} g_s \right|
$$

and 
$$
\left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} \int_0^s f_u \ d \mu_u \right| \leq 
\left| \sup_{0 < s < 1/2} \int_0^s f_u \ d \mu_u \right|
+ \left| \sup_{1/2 < s < 1} \int_{1/2}^s f_u \ d \mu_u \right|.
$$

I think both inequalities are true in general. I argue about them as follows: assume that the maximum is at $s^*$, then

$$
\left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} (f_s + g_s) \right|  = 
\left| f_{s^*} + g_{s^*} \right| \leq 
\left| f_{s^*} \right| + \left| g_{s^*} \right|
\leq \left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} f_{s} \right| + \left| 
\sup_{0 < s < 1} g_{s} \right|
$$

I can also argue for the second inequality using a similar idea by considering the two cases: when $s^*$ is in $[0,1/2]$ and when it's in $[1/2,1]$. However, I don't think this proof is correct in general, since such an $s^*$ might not exist.

How would I go about proving these inequalities in general?

Comment: What are $f_s$ and $g_s$?

Comment: By $f_s$, do you simply mean $f(s)$ or something else?

Comment: Yes, $f_s$ is just $f(s)$

Comment: @Calvin, Yes, that's why I don't think my proof is correct in general. Is there a way to rigorously prove these inequalities, if they are true?

Comment: @Tohiko sorry I only noticed your remark after commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f_s = -1-s$ and $g_s = -1+s$ on $(0,1)$. Then $f_s + g_s = -2$, so

$$|\sup_{s\in(0,1)}( f_s + g_s)| =2 > 1 + 0 =|\sup_{s\in(0,1)} (-1-s)| + |\sup_{s\in(0,1)} (-1+s)| $$

Remark: it is not just the inability to achieve the supremums that is important; the next step that fails in your attempt is
$$ \left| f_{s^*} \right| + \left| g_{s^*} \right|
\leq \left| \sup_{0 < s < 1} f_{s} \right| + \left| 
\sup_{0 < s < 1} g_{s} \right|$$
and to violate this I used functions that can take negative values and the fact that  $\sup f = -\inf (-f)$.

With regards to the second inequality, you didn't choose the measure $\mu$ so let me choose the Dirac mass at 1/2. Then $RHS = 0$ but LHS could be positive, by choosing any $f$ with $f(1/2)>0$.

Comment: Thanks! I now see where I made the mistake. The first inequality should have had the absolute value inside the supremum on the RHS, not outside. For the second inequality, would it be satisfied for "nicer" measures? Such as Lebesgue or Brownian Motion?.

Comment: @Tohiko I don't know, maybe you should ask a new question about that