# Sup inequalites

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

This is a follow-up to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867039/sup-inequalties) with, hopefully, the correct inequalities.

I am trying to check if these following inequalities are true

$$
\sup_{0 < s < 1} \left| (f(s) + g(s)) \right| \leq 
\sup_{0 < s < 1}  \left| f(s) \right| +  \sup_{0 < s < 1} \left| g(s) \right|
$$

and 
$$
\sup_{0 < s < 1} \left| \int_0^s f(u) \ d \mu(u) \right| \leq 
\sup_{0 < s < 1/2}\left|  \int_0^s f(u) \ d \mu(u) \right|
+ \sup_{1/2 < s < 1} \left|  \int_{1/2}^s f(u) \ d \mu(u) \right|.
$$

where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Unlike my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867039/sup-inequalties), the absolute values are inside the sup.

I think both inequalities are true in general. I argue about them as follows: assume that the maximum is at $s^*$, then

$$
\sup_{0 < s < 1} \left| (f(s) + g(s)) \right|  = 
\left| f(s^*) + g(s^*) \right| \leq 
\left| f(s^*) \right| + \left| g(s^*) \right|
\leq \sup_{0 < s < 1}  \left| f(s) \right| + \sup_{0 < s < 1} \left|  g({s}) \right|
$$

I can also argue for the second inequality using a similar idea by considering the two cases: when $s^*$ is in $[0,1/2]$ and when it's in $[1/2,1]$. However, I don't think this proof is correct in general, since such an $s^*$ might not exist.

How would I go about proving these inequalities in general?

Also, is the inequality with $\mu$ true for other measures as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is wrong because the two supremums may be attained at different points. A correct proof is as follows: $|f(t)+g(t)| \leq |f(t)|+|g(t)| \leq \sup \{|f(s)|: 0<s<1\}+\sup \{|g(s)|: 0<s<1\} $. This is true for all $t$. Take sup over $t$ to get the first inequality. The second one is similar since the integral over $(0,s)$ splits into integral over $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,s)$ is $s >1/2$ (and you can bound by just the first term on the right side when $s<1/2$.